# Выделить кругом рабочую область OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, графика, компьютерное-зрение

Имеется прямоугольное фото, но рабочая область круглая и при том на фото имеется небольшой ободок-блик, который необходимо устранить.

Как можно выделить необходимую область и в дальнейшем работать именно с массивом данных из заданного кругом диапазона?

Возможно есть какая-то функция для указания радиуса рабочей области, но она мне неизвестна.

Нужно получить рабочую область, которая выделена белым кругом, ободок выше круга тоже отсечём вместе с чёрным фоном.
[image]

В изображении после обработки пропадёт белая сыпь в виде ободка, т.к в исходном изображении данный диапазон будет исключён
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('flowers.jpg', 1)
image = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.2, fy=0.2)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_range = np.array([169, 100, 100], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_range = np.array([189, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)

cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('image', image)

while(1):
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if(k == 27):
        break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `mask` и `img` откуда у вас?

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Откроем наше изображения
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\al8x3.png', 1)

# Преобразуем изображения в черно-белое что бы убрать свечение
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Преобразуем обратно в BGR
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
# Преобразуем в HSV для удобства в создании маски
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Определение диапазона цвета
lower_range = np.array([0, 0, 200], dtype=np.uint8) # Нижний порог диапазона цвета
upper_range = np.array([0, 0, 255], dtype=np.uint8) # верхний порог

# Создание маски для выделения области
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)

# Поиск контуров на маске
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Создаём массив, который имеет тот же размер как у image, но заполненный нулями
circle_mask = np.zeros_like(image)

# Рисуем все контуры на маске и заполняем область внутри белым цветом.
if len(contours) > 0:
    cv2.drawContours(circle_mask, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    
# Сохраняем все point пикселей из circle_mask, которые имеют белый цвет (255, 255, 255)
white_pixels_point = np.where(circle_mask == [255, 255, 255])

new_image = np.zeros_like(image)

# Проходим по каждой найденной точке и отмечаем ее на новом изображении
for i in range(len(white_pixels_point[0])):
    y = white_pixels_point[0][i]
    x = white_pixels_point[1][i]
    # Устанавливаем красный цвет по найденным координатам
    new_image[y, x] = (0, 0, 255)

cv2.imshow('Points Image', new_image)
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\al8x3copy.png', new_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Пример результата *(изображение взял из вопроса, обрезал шапку)*:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]